# Teams tenant app - "Built for <company_name>" tab does not appear in Applications Tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

Our customer had a tenant app that contains a chatbot installed (through Apps > Upload custom app > for my tenant) that we wanted to uninstall.

They uninstalled the app successfully. The "Built for " tab then disappeared from the Apps tab because it was the only tenant app they used.

We then installed a new tenant app that contains another chatbot. The "Built for " tab appeared briefly and the customer was able to attempt to install the app to a team. However, a popup appeared saying "An error occurred".

Then, after relogging, the "Built for " tab had disappeared.

Attempting to upload the app again led to the message "The application already exists". Relogging had no effect. At this point, we cannot upload the app again and we cannot install it into any team.

How do we resolve this?

Please note creating a new app is not an option we favor, everything has been set up with a specific app. Also, the app appears in the Teams admin panel, tagged as a custom app and tagged as "Allowed". Additionally, we checked app policies and there does not seem to be an issue there either - the fact that the customer, logged onto Teams, was able to delete the previous app shows that it should not be a permission issue.

Comment: Can you please share the error screen? You are receiving message "The already exist" because app is present in the tenant. You need to delete the app and install it again.

Comment: Hi @Abhijit-MSFT, I don't have the message at hand but it's a generic "An error has occurred" message, there is no error code, no detail, etc. It is not possible to delete the app because the tab "Built by <company_name>" does not appear

Comment: In case you have manifest in hand - try updating the version and install app again.

Comment: We were able to delete the app via Powershell, however installing again led to the same behavior. We don't know what to do and this is becoming a pressing matter. :(

Comment: We have been able to correctly upload the app now, it may have been a Permissions issue but it is unsure.

Comment: Thats great, Thanks for letting me know.